# как правильно работать с поддоменами в Nginx?

Tags: nginx, dns, gunicorn

Настроил сервер с Nginx и создал поддомен. Подключил к нему запись типа A со сылкой на статический ip основного домена

Как мне из git напрмер пушить исходники именно на поддомен? Сейчас получается что он просто отображает главную страницу сайта...

Answer (score 0):

вы же указали эти два доменных имени в разных секция `server`. вот и укажите разные каталоги в директиве `root` в этих секциях:

```
server {
  server_name имя1;
  root /путь/к/файлам/для/домена/имя1;
  ...
}
server {
  server_name имя2;
  root /путь/к/файлам/для/домена/имя2;
  ...
}
```

соответственно, и http-страницы (и иные файлы) разместите в этих каталогах.

Comment: нет, у меня пока только одно указано.

буду пробовать по вашему рецепту перераспределить запросы